# Implementing '+' operator for std::vector

Tags: c++, overloading

I'm trying to add support for addition for std::vector. Here's the code I have so far.. The part that doesn't work is the part where I attempt to print the result. I am aware of valarray but I can't get it to work the way that I want (mostly I haven't found an easy way to convert  vectors into valarrays).

This is the error:

```
../src/VectorOperations.cpp:26:6: error: need 'typename' before 'std::vector<T>::iterator' because 'std::vector<T>' is a dependent scope
```

---

```
class VectorOperations
{
public:
    //Vector Operations
    std::vector<double> logv(std::vector<double> first);
    std::vector<double> raiseTo(std::vector<double> first, int power);
    std::vector<double> xthRoot(std::vector<double> first, int xth);
    double sumv(std::vector<int> first);

    std::vector<double> operator + ( const std::vector<double> & ) const;
    std::vector<double> operator - ( const std::vector<double> & ) const;
    std::vector<double> operator * ( const std::vector<double> & ) const;
    std::vector<double> operator / ( const std::vector<double> & ) const;

};


template <typename T>
std::vector<T> operator+(const std::vector<T>& a, const std::vector<T>& b)
{
    assert(a.size() == b.size());
    std::vector<T> result;
    result.reserve(a.size());
    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(),
               std::back_inserter(result), std::plus<T>());

    std::cout<<"Results from addition follow: \n";
    //HERE'S THE PROBLEM: I WANT TO PRINT OUT BUT I GET ERRORS
        for(std::vector<T>::iterator it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it) {
            /* std::cout << *it; ... */
        }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Well.. you have <double> in the class method declaration yet you use <T> for the method definition. Rest is up to you to figure out.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler error tell you *exactly* what to do?

Comment: Also, you're defining a free function. `class VectorOperations` is completely irrelevant here!

Comment: The best thing for delayed operations on arrays are the `expression templates`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler error tells you ***exactly*** what to do. However, rather than roll your own `for`-loop, I recommend using [**`std::copy()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3aSearch&search=std%3a%3acopy):

```
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(os, ", "));
```

For example:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<T> const& v)
{
    os << "{";
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(os, ", "));
    return os << "}";
}
```

[Apply your own formatting style to taste.]

Then you can call:

```
std::cout << "Results from addition follow: \n" << result << std::endl;
```

[Preferably from ***outside*** `operator +`, as this would be an unexpected side-effect of adding two `vector`s.]

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<T>::iterator` depends on template type, try to add `typename`:

```
for(typename std::vector<T>::iterator it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it) {
    ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

add typename before `std::vector<T>::iterator it`. It should be `typename std::vector<T>::iterator`
You can refer to this SO link for detal information about typename [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)